# Simpler way to write the following instructions?

Tags: assembly, avr

Hey guys so for the following code:

```
 brbc 4, method
 brbs 2, method
```

What is an easier and more common way of writing this in AVR assembly?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SREG is I T H S V N Z C.

So you want to branch if S is cleared , or N is set.

S = N XOR S, so S is cleared if N and V, or not N and not V. That is, if the result is positive or zero.

N is set when the result is negative.

So you want to branch always.

```
jmp method
```

Comment: Ok that is very much helpful; however, it seems like that will not always be the case... If the code were to be brbc 4 brbs 2 brbc 0 brbc 7. I could not just write jmp method. Correct?

Comment: @Jonny You could just write `jmp method`. The last two would never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

BRBC is a jump if a SREG.s = 0, where s is 2 or 0 in your code; what do you want to do in your code?

Comment: Sorry I entered the question wrong but I have fixed it. I am just working through textbook questions and it asks me to write the more common alias of the code I have entered in my question!

Comment: OK, so you want to go to "method" subprog if: a) result of a previous operation is greater then zero or b) most significant bit of a result equal to 1, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more common is using

```
brge method
brmi method
```

instead of your code

Comment: And if you studied Timothy Margush's "Some Assembly Required:..." book, I think answer about jmp is incorrect, because excercise is to write common alias for EACH of the instructions, nor for sequence...